# Python doctest: have a common initialization for several tests

Tags: python, doctest

I want to have a doctest for a class, where the use of the class needs a somehow lengthy setup. Like:

```py
class MyClass
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def bar(self):
        """Do bar

            >>> # do a multiline generation of foo
                ... ...
            >>> myoby = MyClass(foo)
            >>> print(myobj.bar())
            BAR
        """
        …

    def foobar(self):
        """Do foobar

            >>> # do a multiline generation of foo
                ... ...
            >>> myoby = MyClass(foo)
            >>> print(myobj.foobar())
            FOOBAR
        """
        …
```

My real case has ~8 methods that I want to document and pytest. Repeating the generation of foo everywhere contradicts the DRY principle, and also generated quite lengthy and unreadable documentation. Is there a way to avoid it?

Optimally would be like

```py
class MyClass
    """My class

    An example way to create the 'foo' argument is

        >>> # do a multiline generation of foo
            ... ...
    """
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def bar(self):
        """Do bar

            >>> myoby = MyClass(foo)
            >>> print(myobj.bar())
            BAR
        """
        …

    def foobar(self):
        """Do foobar

            >>> myoby = MyClass(foo)
            >>> print(myobj.foobar())
            FOOBAR
        """
        …
```

Comment: Where should I put this? I usually run doctest as part of pytest, but the examples show only to put this into the `__main__` of the module (which is quite ugly).

Comment: Will you accept a solution using `pytest --doctest-modules`?  Or is this limited to the builtin doctest suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggling, I found the following solution, (ab)using a submodule of my own module:

```py
class MyClass
    """My class

    An example way to create the 'foo' argument is::

        >>> # do a multiline generation of foo
        >>> foo = ...

    .. only:: doctest

        >>> import mymodule.tests
        >>> mymodule.tests.foo = foo

    """
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def bar(self):
        """Do bar

        .. only:: doctest

            >>> import mymodule.tests
            >>> foo = mymodule.tests.foo

        Here is a good example, using the initialization above::

            >>> myoby = MyClass(foo)
            >>> print(myobj.bar())
            BAR
        """
        …
```

The "tricks":

- I abuse my `mypackage.tests` submodule to store the results of the initialization. This works, since the modules are not re-initialized in subsequent tests
- Doctest (at least in pytest) doesn't care about code blocks, it just looks for the appropriate patterns and indentions. Any block is fine, even a conditional one (`.. only::`). The condition (`doctest`) is arbitrary, it just needs to be evaluated to false so that the block isn't displayed.

I am still not sure how robust this is with respect to future developments of doctest/pytest and sphinxdoc.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you are using `pytest --doctest-modules` which is hinted at in the question/comments, but isn't explicit.  See [pytest using fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/doctest.html#using-fixtures).  If you don't need the documentation to include the steps to make `foo` argument, a fixture will work.  `getfixture` is mentioned in the documentation for doctest, but it is hard to find documentation specifically for it.

```py
# conftest.py

import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def foo_setup():
    foo = [100, 10]  # make a complex foo
    return foo
```

```py
# my_module.py
class MyClass:
    """
    My class.
    >>> foo = getfixture('foo_setup')
    >>> # consider printing details of foo here
    >>> myobj = MyClass(foo)
    >>> myobj.foo
    [100, 10]
    """

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def foobar(self):
        """
        foobar appends 0 to foo.

        >>> foo = getfixture('foo_setup')
        >>> myobj = MyClass(foo)
        >>> myobj.foobar()
        >>> myobj.foo
        [100, 10, 0]
        """
        self.foo.append(0)
```

Comment: What I don't really like here is that there is a specific function `getfixture()`, which doesn't really make sense for an average reader of the documentation, and would then need to be explained. IMO the solution wit `.. only::` produces a better readable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `foo` into the namespace using a fixture.  This avoids having any extraneous lines in each doctest.  [Documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/doctest.html#doctest-namespace-fixture).

```py
# mymodule.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def foo_setup(doctest_namespace):
    doctest_namespace["foo"] = [100, 10]  # make a complex foo

# my_module.py
class MyClass:
    """
    My class.
    >>> # consider printing details of foo here
    >>> myobj = MyClass(foo)
    >>> myobj.foo
    [100, 10]
    """

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def foobar(self):
        """
        foobar appends 0 to foo.

        >>> myobj = MyClass(foo)
        >>> myobj.foobar()
        >>> myobj.foo
        [100, 10, 0]
        """
        self.foo.append(0)
```